# Updated list does not get used in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
import math

array = [16,5,3,4,11,9,13]


for x in array[0:len(array)-1]:
    key=x
    index=array.index(x)
    posj=index
    for y in array[index+1:len(array)]:
        if y<key:
            key=y
            posj=array.index(y)
    if index!=posj:
        hold=array[index]
        array[index]=key
        array[posj]=hold


print(array)
```

I'm trying to implement insertion sort.
It appears after using the debugger that in every loop iteration, it is using the array [16,5,3,4,11,9,13] instead of the updated array that results after a loop iteration.

How can I make x be the updated element for the given indicie?

Comment: `array[0:len(array)-1]` creates a copy of `array`

Comment: I see. Then how do I keep this copy updated?

Comment: Since you haven't assigned the copy to any variable you can't. I'm also unsure why you are creating a copy at all instead of iterating over the array by index

Comment: Good point, I guess my ignorance with Python is showing. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for x in array[0:len(array)-1]:
```

try

```
for x in array:
```

### Output

```
[3, 4, 5, 9, 11, 13, 16]
```

Comment: Doing it this way leaves me with only the option of iterating through every element though. How can I iterate through only n-1 elements without making a copy of the array? Not that it matters in this particular implementation, but for future refrence I would like to know.

Comment: use a counter and break condition

Comment: So what the difference between your solution and `array[0:len(array)]`.

Comment: array[0:len(array)] creates a copy